# Using OpenVPN, yet netflix.com blocks access

Tags: proxy, openvpn, vps, geolocation, netflix

I have set up an OpenVPN server on a VPS in the USA and configured it to route all clients traffic through it. Everything seems to work fine regarding the VPN connection in gerneral. All ip lookup sites show me the us server's ip address and even hulu.com works(it won't work if you are not in the usa). But for some reason netflix.com says "Sorry, Netflix is not available in your country yet.". So I thought that netflix probably uses some more sophisticated ways to determine your location beyond just your ip address. But I could not find a way to get it to work until I dropped the idea of using a VPN and instead connected to the server via a simple socks tunnel with ssh by running:

`ssh -D 9999 user@serverip`

All I had to do was changing the key

`network.proxy.socks_remote_dns`

in Firefox from false to true to prevent DNS leaks and setting up the socks proxy. Then I could finally watch netflix.com. As a result I concluded that there is nothing in the browser(or something like system timezone) that tells netflix the location, so it has to have something to do with the OpenVPN config.

After that I used tcpdump to log all the traffic on the server's network interface venet0 (OpenVZ VPS), visited netflix.com on the client while first connected to the VPN and then connected via socks tunnel and afterwards compared both outputs.

The only thing that caught my eye was that while using the socks tunnel the server mainly used ipv6 to connect to netflix whereas it only used ipv4 when the client was connected to the OpenVPN server. But I don't get how that could make such a difference.

So what am I missing? Is there a way to configure OpenVPN to also use ipv6 to connect to a website although there is only an ipv4 connection between the VPS and the client?

Here is the server.conf of the OpenVPN server (OpenVZ VPS)

```
local serverip
port 443
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ./easy-rsa2/keys/ca.crt
cert ./easy-rsa2/keys/vps1.crt
key ./easy-rsa2/keys/vps1.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh ./easy-rsa2/keys/dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
max-clients 4
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 3
```

iptables forwarding

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source serverip
```

(enabled ipv4 forwarding)

I have tried everything always on a Win7 and a Debian client with only ipv4 connections and always made sure that they use the correct DNS server (tested with ipleak.net and tcpdump / wireshark).

client.conf:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote serverip 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
ns-cert-type server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
comb-lzo
verb 3
```

Comment: Be aware Windows 10 sends DNS request across all NICs

Comment: It is my understanding that Netflix bans certain IP address of known VPN services.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will solve your Netflix problems (though I suppose it its possible that Netflix does not geolocate you the same over IPv4 and IPv6), but since OpenVPN 2.3, there is full support for IPv6.

Just use `server-ipv6 addr/bits` with bits between 64 and 112.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and the client successfully got an ipv6 connection to the OpenVPN server (tun interface) although the client has an ipv4-only connection to the internet but I cannot surf the web with ipv6 on the client as it seems to only route ipv4 traffic through the VPN connection. Thus netflix still doesn't work.

Comment: Try adding ` push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"` to your config. See also the OpenVPN page on IPv6: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IPv6

Comment: Their not DNS snooping are they just a bit of a coincidence you said it worked when you set it up to specifically route the DNS through the proxy, maybe check if DNS leaks aren't happening on the VPN as most people's downfalls of using anonymising software is this.